# MSDTC on RDS - no Active Directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, msdtc

I have SQL Server 2019 STD RDS that is not domain joined and it's only accessible inside VPC (no public IP). I have an internal AD domain and several web servers joined to that internal AD inside VPC. MDTC is configured to with no auth on those EC2 instance and also on RDS. When I try distributed transaction initiated from the web app (on the EC2 instance) I get following error:

> The MSDTC transaction manager was unable to pull the transaction from the source transaction manager due to communication problems. Possible causes are: a firewall is present and it doesn't have an exception for the MSDTC process, the two machines cannot find each other by their NetBIOS names, or the support for network transactions is not enabled for one of the two transaction managers. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004D02B)

DNS resolution should be working on that RDS, I can't check since xp_cmd_shell can't be enabled to try it out so RDS should resolve EC2 instances, DNS servers are set on VPC DHCP settings. Security rules are currently to allow everything while I am troubleshooting. I did everything like I usually do without RDS

RDS option group settings

```
ENABLE_SNA_LU   true
ALLOW_OUTBOUND_CONNECTIONS  true
ALLOW_INBOUND_CONNECTIONS   true
ENABLE_XA   true
TRANSACTION_LOG_SIZE    4
AUTHENTICATION  NONE
```

The only question left here is, do I need active directory joined RDS for this to work (and ofc all servers joined to that same AD)? From all the docs and videos available this should work, but didn't find info anywhere is being part of AD hard prereq or not.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: Yes with the help of AWS support. So, RDS instance has some internal computer name `SELECT @@SERVERNAME` which when you find out need to add AD DNS server since the AD joined web servers are looking for that hostname when DTC is initiated. That name changes once in a few months (probably related to the maintenance that AWS is doing and when SQL instance is moved to another host) so when that happens you need to update DNS with new hostname otherwise MSDTC will stop working.

Comment: And in theory if you don't deploy AD inside your VPC, adding host record on web server should do the trick too.